# Get a text between two words using sed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sed

I want to find the text which are coming in between two words, and this two words are not on same line, both are present on different lines, so I want to find the lines (text of lines) which are coming in between words

For example:

```
example-a, pqr- 411 037.            ] .. abc.

V/s.

xyz abc Transports Ltd.,            ]
517, E, M. G. road,                 ]
hhhh.                               ] ..pqr.

I am doing the testing for example:
example.com
```

Now I want a text which is coming after the `V/s.` till the `...pqr` next line and `..pqr` next line is a empty line.

I used `sed -nr '/v[/s]\.*/I{ :loop; n; /\.\.pqr/Iq; p; b loop}' input_file.txt`

But its giving the text till `hhhh.           ] ..pqr` but I want next line also how could I achieve this with sed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
sed -nr '/V\/s\.*/I { :loop; n; p; /\.\.pqr/I { :loop2; n; p; // b loop2; /^\s*$/ q }; b loop}' foo.txt
```

is the most straightforward adaptation.

That is:

```
/^V\/s/I {     # starting in a line that starts with v/s
               # (you can go back to your old pattern if my guess about the
               # precise criteria you want here is incorrect)
  :loop
  n            # fetch the next line
  p            # print it
  /\.\.pqr/I { # if it contained ..pqr
    :loop2
    n          # fetch
    p          # and print lines
    // b loop2 # until one does not contain ..pqr (// repeats the previous regex)
               # this inner loop is necessary in case there are two lines
               # containing ..pqr at the end of a section.
    /^\s*$/ q  # and if that line was empty, quit.
  }
  b loop       # loop until then
}
```

I changed the pattern in the beginning because it appears to me that `v[/s]\.*` is the result of guesswork until the right thing happened with an excample file. `v[/s]\.*` will match `v/.`, `vs.`, `v/...` and `vs...`, but not `v/s.` -- the `[]` denote a character set from which any one can match, not a sequence -- `[/s]` matches either `/` or `s`.

The pattern I put in will match `v/s` at the beginning of a line. Alternatively (depending on what your needs are), you could use `/v\/s/I`, which will match `v/s` anywhere in the line, or perhaps `/^v\/s\.*$/`, which will only match lines that consist wholly of `v/s` followed by an arbitrary number of periods.

Mind you, all of this is some guesswork because I don't know precisely what uniquely identifies the start of a section in your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '\#V/s\.#,/\.\.pqr/ {
   \#V/s\.# b
   /\.\.pqr/ n
   p
   }' YourFile
```

print all the lines for **ALL sections** starting line next to `V/s.` until first line after first `pqr...` on another line.

Answer (score 0):

I would have used `awk` like this:

```
awk '/V\/s\./ {f=1} /\.\.pqr/ && f {a=1} !NF && a {f=a=0} f' file
V/s.

xyz abc Transports Ltd.,            ]
517, E, M. G. road,                 ]
hhhh.                               ] ..pqr.
```

This will print from found `Vs.` until `..pqr` and next line is empty.

How it works:

```
awk '
/V\/s\./ {f=1}          # If "Vs." is found set flag "f"
/\.\.pqr/ && f {a=1}    # If "..pqe" is found and flag "f" is true, set flag "a"
!NF && a {f=a=0}        # If line is blank and "a" is true clear all flags
f                       # If flag "f" is true print the line. 
' file
```